# Does a visa run in Taiwan really involve applying for a new visa every time, or just relying on visa-exempt passport entry?

Tags: visas, us-citizens, taiwan, visa-runs

**Background:**
I've lived in Taiwan for 3 years now, always with an ARC (as I've always been employed by a Taiwanese company with the power to apply for an ARC for me up until now).  I've applied for a 6th month ARC extension for "seeking work" since I quit my last job, but I won't be getting another job with a company that can apply for a visa for me, so I'm looking to start doing the whole "leave the country every 3 months" thing that I've heard so much about (I am from a visa-exempt country [I'm a US citizen], so from what I understand I can stay in the country for 90 days without an ARC.)

From other answers I've read ([Taiwan maximum stay rules with reentry](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24749/taiwan-maximum-stay-rules-with-reentry)) it would seem that this isn't frowned upon and can be done rather regularly and quickly (in a one-day visa run to HK).

**My questions are:**

**1)** Do I have to actually go through a visa application process to do this, or is what I would really by doing just leaving the country and coming back, relying on my passport for 90 day visa-exempt entry?

**2)** Do I have to go to HK or can I go to any country, like Japan? Would China even count, since they don't like to admit Taiwan is a separate country?

Comment: Visa runs usually require that you depart, enter another country, then return.  It doesn't much matter which country you go to, as you as you have been stamped out of Taiwan and stamped in somewhere else. They wouldn't much like it if you "departed", hung out in the airport departure lounge then "arrived" a few minutes later.  But ultimately the question is: Are you willing to risk deportation for working on a visitor entry stamp?